# plt.cm.RdBu ( Cannot find reference in cm.py )

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, heatmap, colormap

The following code snippet is supposed to show a heatmap of a dataset, like the first image:

```py
colormap = plt.cm.RdBu
plt.figure(figsize=(18, 15))
plt.title('Pearson Correlation of Features', y=1.05, size=50)
sns.heatmap(df.corr(), linewidths=0.1, vmax=1.0, square=True, cmap=colormap, linecolor='white', annot=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, my `RdBu` is highlighted in PyCharm and the warning message says:

> **Cannot find reference 'RdBu' in 'cm.py'**

There are a few posts that basically show the syntax is correct and I am not missing any packages. What am I doing wrong here that I get this empty map instead?

[image]

Comment: have you checked your input data? This looks very much like your input is just 1x1

Comment: @Eumel The input data is fine. All the methods work and show that the input is OK. Here is the [tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/gabbygab/predicting-the-risk-of-diabetes) I am following. I think the problem is `plt.cm.RdBu` but don't know how to fix it?

Comment: Does it work using a different colormap?

Comment: Do you mean just replacing `heatmap` with a different map?

Comment: @CatarinaRuna yes, exactly

Comment: Thank you both (@Eumel & @Andrea) for looking into this. I found what I was missing. I will post an answer shortly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the following code before the graph code:

```
for c in df.columns:
    if df[c].dtype == 'object':
        lbl = LabelEncoder()
        lbl.fit(list(df[c].values))
        df[c] = lbl.transform(list(df[c].values))
```